# Connect to a Java Derby Database through the internet

Tags: java, database, connection-string, derby

i am making an application for a maintenance office ... the user(owner) want to manage his work remotely like from another country ... i would like your help to lead me or clarify how could it be done

what was in my mind when i accepted the project was a connection string like this :

```
"jdbc:derby:MOfficeDB;create=false;user=app;password=any;remotehost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

where `xxx` is the global IP ... and iam not sure of `remotehost`

Comment: Let us check... which is his IP?

Comment: dont know yet ... but i told him it will have to be a static ip ... i understand from your comment that the connection string i wrote is the right form ?

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#url_ns_client

Comment: or do you mean which is the ip address in the string ... itis the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip V4

Comment: @SJuan76 but i dont see where to write the global or external IP ... or isnt it necessary ... but if it isnt necessary then how it will know which country or so

Comment: Do not publish your database to the internet.

The databases aren't really designed for that kind of exposure.

We have all of these tools, frameworks, patterns, etc. that are basically designed to isolate the database behind a layer of logic and protection.

It's certainly more work to do so, but you really should consider putting a small application layer in front of your database, and securing it properly.

Comment: @WillHartung so you mean i make the client application talk to the server application by using sockets or so would be more secure ... but a it will require more work (coding) !! did i get that right ?

Comment: @OmAr - Yes, it is more work. But it is a much better solution as it offers more security, more control, more flexibility. It allows for higher level apis to your application rather than simply raw storage. Publishing APIs via SOAP or JSON web services is not a high burden today, and the benefits far outweigh the costs, even on a simple application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the Derby Network Server: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/cadminov825266.html